# askdifferent.com does not redirect when HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed

- http://askdifferent.com performs a 301 redirect to http://apple.stackexchange.com.
- https://askdifferent.com doesn't work: connection refused.

With the move to HTTPS across Stack Exchange, can the HTTPS redirection be functional?

A more minor related issue: can the redirect from the HTTP redirect *directly* to the HTTPS URL?

Comment: to turn it around... did it ever work with https? why do you expect it to work now? During the move we've rewritten all askdifferent.com links to apple.se, there are no links to askdifferent in the network anymore, only external ones, and those were never https, since it never worked. This behavior is the same of other pointer domains as well (e.g. miyodeya.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: This will happen as a result of mostly unrelated cleanup efforts.

---

To clarify our position here: there were no plans to make the redirect-only domains available over `https://`. They were never at any point in time supported, nor do we generate links to them - so all links in existence should be `http://`.

Even if they were `https://`, they wouldn't get the benefits of `https://` anyway, since they're just 301s to the site's real domain). There's really very little reason to take on the certificate complexity and cost to add these additional domains.

Not that being said, this will eventually happen anyway for other reasons. As simply as a side-effect of us shuffling redirects between [name.com](https://www.name.com/) servers and [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for redirects. We did this for [miyodeya.com](https://miyodeya.com) for the purposes of *existing* SE 1.0 links - since they ever existed, not supporting this on name.com's redirect service was causing (effectively) 404s to actual content.

We moved them to our miscellaneous Cloudflare account for the purposes of redirects, supporting `https://` is only a side-effect. But, maintaining 2 ways of doing something when 1 is saner/easier (we're almost done automating this) is just silly. So the plan is to move all these domains to Cloudflare. Here's the list:

- nothingtoinstall.com
- seasonedadvice.com
- crossvalidated.com
- basicallymoney.com
- chiphacker.com
- brewadvice.com
- askpatents.com
- miyodeya.com

I don't have an exact timeline as the main dev on the sync bits for Cloudflare/page rules is currently moving and out for a little while. Roughly, I'd say in the next month or two.

Comment: Should be done much sooner than a month or two. Just finalizing and merging in our code to manage cloudflare redirects. https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol/pull/119 is the PR on that, just needs a couple of safety features and I will wire up all those alias domains to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have finished automating this, and askdifferent.com redirects should be working much better than they were. I expect all of these urls to properly redirect properly over http and https(possibly pending DNS ttl expiry):

- https://askdifferent.com/questions/9659
- https://meta.askdifferent.com/questions/3027
- https://chat.askdifferent.com

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update! May I ask why the redirects are 302 over 301?

Comment: The 302s are just temporary while we validate and roll out the automated setup for them. Will convert to 301s once we are fully confident they will work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get this over to the main thread for https transition.

- [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)

According to the main post we should be **status: done** with only chat not on https.

Comment: Why does this need to be moved to main meta? It only affects this site

Comment: It doesn't need to go. It just could go. Other sites with side identities need cleanup too in all likelihood. Looks like we have an answer now, though.